Puppeteer- why did my dropdown locator not working?
I have this dropdown on my page
<select class="form-select">
  <option disabled="" value="none">Choose Option</option>
  <option value="value-1">Option One</option>
  <option value="value-2">Option 2</option>
</select>

This is my dropdown click code
Already tried this code before and still not working
const targetPage = page;
await page.click('select.form-select');
await page.select('select.form-select', 'value-1');

I don't understand why the locator keep failing to find my dropdown and why it doesn't choose any option. Please help me to fix my code.

Please share a [mcve], with the page you're automating and a high-level goal you're trying to accomplish (there may be an easier way to do it than this). Thanks.

This is the latest code I use
const targetPage = page;
await page.click('select.form-select');
await page.select('select.form-select', 'value-1');

Forgot to mention I export this directly from Chrome Recorder and tweak it myself afterwards

Thanks, but that's not enough information to help. Please provide all the information requested in my first comment: (1) your actual goal, (2) the page you're automating, (3) complete, runnable code. Ideally also a package.json with versions.
